# How to draw a tick in the mid of a line segment for Manim animation?

Tags: python, geometry, manim

### Problem

I want to mark two line segments as of equal length using ticks, like it is commonly done in geometry. [image].

Despite my search effort, I failed to find a simple build-in solution for this.

### My bulky solution

Of course, one can draw ticks directly if a line segment is given. For example, I do it as follows.

```py
from manim import *

class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        line = Line()
        line.shift(3 * RIGHT + UP).rotate(35 * DEGREES)
        
        # Adding a tick at the center of the line as submobject
        size = 0.1
        tick = Line (size * DOWN, size * UP)
        tick.rotate(line.get_angle())
        tick.move_to(line.get_center())
        line.add(tick)
        
        self.add(line)
```

### Question

What is the best practice to add ticks to Line object?

Comment: What aspect of your solution don't you like? For instance, constructing the orthogonal vector of (x, y) is done efficiently and numerically accurately by (-y, x).  Is this the kind of "best practice" you ask for?

Comment: I'm looking for an elegant and concise way of adding ticks to a line object like `line.add_tick_at_mid(number_of_ticks)`, if any